# How create validation mysql with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, validation

I need to create a validation with js so that the page does not reload when you want to display the error message, so that the video background does not stop.

This is what I have for now.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" method="post" >
    <p class="error"><?php echo $mensajeLogin; ?></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="user" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['user'])) { echo $_POST['user']; } ?>"/>
        <span class="input-icon fui-user"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pass" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['pass'])) { echo $_POST['pass']; } ?>"/>
        <span class="input-icon fui-lock"></span>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-hg btn-primary" type="submit" name="enviar_login" value="Iniciar sesión">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
function VerificarLogin($cTabla,$cUsuario,$cPass) {

  $conn = ConectarBD();
  $vConsulta="SELECT ID, usuario, id_cuenta, email FROM $cTabla WHERE usuario like '$cUsuario' and pass like '$cPass' ";

  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $vConsulta)) {

      /* execute statement */
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      /* bind result variables */
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $user, $id_cuenta, $email);

      /* fetch values */
      $vListado = array();
      $i=0;
      while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $id, $provincia);
          $vListado[$i]['id']=$id;          
          $vListado[$i]['user']=$user;
          $vListado[$i]['id_cuenta']=$id_cuenta;
          $vListado[$i]['email']=$email;
          $i++;
      }


      /* close statement */
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }
  /* close connection */
  mysqli_close($conn);

  return $vListado;
}

$mensajeLogin = '';

if (!empty($_POST['enviar_login'])) {  

  $_POST['user']=trim($_POST['user']);

  $login=VerificarLogin('usuarios',$_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']);


  if (empty($_POST['user']) && empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $mensajeLogin = "Complete los campos.<br />";

  } elseif (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $mensajeLogin.="Debe ingresar una contraseña.<br />";

  } elseif (empty($login)) {
    $mensajeLogin = 'El usuario y/o contraseña es incorrecto';

  } else {

    $_SESSION['id_user']=$login[0]['id'];
    $_SESSION['nivel']=$login[0]['id_cuenta'];
    $_SESSION['user']=$login[0]['user'];
    $_SESSION['email']=$login[0]['email'];
    header('Location: panel/admin.php');
    exit;
  }

}
```

I only need to add javascript.

Example online [here](http://nicogaldo.com.ar/faketumblr/login.php).

Comment: Excellent! Adding the JavaScript shouldn't be too difficult for you then. Do make some attempts and let us know if you can't get your **JavaScript** code working!

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: need some code to guide me, know little and nothing javascript @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and its $.post method to send data and receive result.

Anyways, never rely on JS validation, always filter the input in PHP code.